# Using Windows GAWK, how to get the executing script's path\name?

Tags: gawk

I am using Windows GAWK version 4.0.1.  ARGV[0] always returns "gawk".  How do I get the path\name of the currently executing GAWK script within that script?

Sure, I can hard code the information in the script, but if I move it to a new directory or decide to rename it, then it will no longer be correct.

Also, I might have multiple copies of some script, or I might execute them from within plug-ins to other programs.  I would like an easy way to see/verify which script is executing...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it.  There is no mechanism provided by GAWK to get this information.